# Get Location info through Microsoft Health Cloud API

Tags: api, microsoft-band

i'm try to get Location info from activity details with Microsoft Health Cloud API. i Have added the ReadActivityLocation scoper on login and MapPoints in request but when i retrive details  MapPoints contains all details but not Location info is always 0 this is an example og MapPoints element returned in json

> {"secondsSinceStart":1278,"mapPointType":"Waypoint","ordinal":24,"actualDistance":59999,"totalDistance":59999,"heartRate":111,"pace":1388000,"scaledPace":15,"speed":72,"location":{"latitude":0,"longitude":0,"elevationFromMeanSeaLevel":0},"isPaused":false,"isResume":false}

What is wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it was a bug back then.

I tried it today, works fine for me.

From User [Bing Hoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5371147/bing-hoo) at this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32816456/cant-get-gps-location-in-map-point-via-microsoft-health-api):

> I send a e-mail to Microsoft , they say it is a bug, and not tell me when to be solve [...]
>
> Microsoft said they have been fix the bug,and I tested it,it's ok now.