# Can`t get GPS location in map point via microsoft health API

Tags: microsoft-band

I want get my run activity location data and use the data in my android app,so I use the Microsoft health cloud API. I can login by using my live ID, and I can read my activity data,include MapPoints, but I can`t get any GPS location information. ‘latitude’ and ‘longitude’ value is 0.
 I have set the scope of oauth2.0 to "offline_access mshealth.ReadProfile mshealth.ReadActivityHistory mshealth.ReadActivityLocation mshealth.ReadDevices",but it still doesn't work.
I use android async httpclient to get data.

```
String msToken = "MSTOKEN...";
String profileUrl = ConstValue.getMSHealthURL(ConstValue.MS_API_HEALTH_URL_ACTIVITIES);
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
params.add("activityIds","2519604437250480855");
params.add("activityIncludes","Details,MapPoints");
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient(true, 80, 443);
msToken =  String.format("bearer %s", msToken);
client.addHeader("Authorization",msToken);
Log.v("mstoken",msToken);
client.get(profileUrl,params, new TextHttpResponseHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int i, Header[] headers, String s, Throwable throwable) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int i, Header[] headers, String s) {
        Log.v("activity",s);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you show us some code of what you tried?

Comment: @Scorpio I add some sample code used for request activities data,thanks for reply

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing (from within a WP8.1 app)

Comment: I send a e-mail to Microsoft , they say it is a bug, and not tell me when to be solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft said they have been fix the bug,and I tested it,it's ok now.